# need to know multiple SIM and Network supported modem

Tags: sms, modem

I want to send sms programmatically by my application [java] for both GSM and CDMA network using a modem which will support multiple SIM card.
Need a modem which will support multi network[GSM,CDMA] + Multi SIM[more than 5] and will also support USB/SerilPort connection. [USB Port is preferred]
I need to know, which modem will be better for me to serve my requirements.
Can anybody help me by giving suggestion with MODEM's model and company.

Answer (score 0):

I am made to believe the Huawei modem seems to works perfectly with a GSM network. I did quite a bit of online searching for various models available, but I wasn't able to find any modem that was compatible with both GSM and CDMA networks (however, I did stick to 'branded' models). As far as multi sim models are concerned, WaveCom seems to be providing devices with upto 64 SIM ports.